# Java ArrayList gives me an Unsafe operations warning

Tags: java, generics

I recently started working on a personal project to test my (lousy) skills in java. It is a basic Java Card game called "Go Fish!". I'm currently only using basic console input/output to make the game. But whenever I compile the class MainClass, the compiler gives me "Unchecked or Unsafe" operations warning. I've been all over the internet looking for solutions, and have tried many, but it keeps giving me that error.

Any ideas on how to get rid of this problem?

**Code: Class MainClass**

```
    import java.util.*;

public class MainClass
{
    //Playing states
    public static final int PLAYING = 0;
    public static final int OVER = 1;

    //Chance states
    public static final int PLAY = 0;
    public static final int COMP = 1;

    //Win conditions.
    public static final int PLAY_WIN = 0;
    public static final int COMP_WIN = 1;

    //Values used in the game, VERY IMPORTANT
    public static int currentState, currentPlayer;
    public static int winner;

    public static ArrayList<String> Player_Cards;
    public static ArrayList<String> Comp_Cards;
    public static ArrayList<String> Deck_Cards;

    public MainClass() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Start Game. This action is carried out EVERYTIME the game is started.
        initGame();  //Serves function for "Initializing" the game i.e. sorting cards, distributing, identifying.
    }

    public static void initGame() {
        //Goto Shuffler, get a shuffled deck, return here.
        Shuffler shuffle = new Shuffler();
        Deck_Cards = new ArrayList<String>(shuffle.doShuffle()); //For safe usage.

        Player_Cards = new ArrayList<String>();
        Comp_Cards = new ArrayList<String>();

        //Give player cards        
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            int c = Deck_Cards.size() - 1 - i;
            Player_Cards.add(Deck_Cards.get(c));
            Deck_Cards.remove(c);
        }

        //Give computer cards       
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Comp_Cards.add(Deck_Cards.get(i));
            Deck_Cards.remove(i);
        }      
        System.out.println("Darp");
    }
}
```

**Code: Class Shuffler:**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Shuffler
{
    public enum Suits {HEARTS, DIAMONDS, CLUBS, SPADES};
    public enum Ranks {ACE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING};

    public Shuffler() {

    }



    public static ArrayList doShuffle() {
        //Initialize cards
        int count = 0;
        ArrayList<String> deck = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < 13; y++) {
                deck.add("Card is " + Ranks.values()[y] + " of " + Suits.values()[i]);
                count++;
            }
        }
        Collections.shuffle(deck);

        return deck;
    }
}
```

*Additional Information:*

I'm using BlueJ for this project

Comment: Try `public static ArrayList<String> doShuffle()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a raw type for the `doShuffle` method so the compiler complains about the lack of type safety. Replace

```
public static ArrayList doShuffle() {
```

with

```
public static List<String> doShuffle() {
```

This method is accessed using an instance of `Shuffler` so the `static` keyword can be omitted

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're using a raw `ArrayList` for your `doShuffle`. The local variable is properly parameterized, so adding `<String>` to the return type should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the doShuffle method returns a generic ArrayList.

In the main you call that method putting the result in an ArrayList so the compiler is advising you that this conversion is unchecked.

You can modify the method making the return ArrayList or use a generic ArraList in the main too.

PS. first answer! xD